# How to build an array of interpolated values for a constant timeframe?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, date, androidplot

i need your help. this question drives me nuts:
i have an android app where you can store your weight with the date in an sqlite DB.
i have an android cursor with the database values. it contains the date (as string, like "30.12.2005") and a float-value (weight).

the cursor may look like this:

03.01.2006 - 83,5
05.01.2006 - 82,5
09.01.2006 - 81,8
01.03.2006 - 82,0
14.03.2006 - 81,6
17.05.2006 - 81,2
22.10.2006 - 81,1
24.01.2007 - 81,0
27.01.2007 - 80,5

i want to show interpolated values in an androidPlot diagramm.
right now i am building interpolated values out of 7 DB-entries
this works, but i want the timeline to have constant timeframes, like 14 days or a month.
(androidplot has a timeSeries that may be easy to use... i have to check that.)

the algorithm should iterate over the cursor and check what entries are within the 14-days timeframe, interpolate them and save the value in a seperate array.
in case there are no values in the 14-days-timeframe it should interpolate the closest two values....

i have no clue how the algorithm should look like ...
what could be a good approach for an algorithm?

bye
phil

Comment: well apart from the interpolation method, everything else looks pretty trivial to implement. are you looking for simple linear interpolation, or some sort of smooth fitting?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i use at the moment for setting up an array and calculating a second array with interpolated values

```
    Cursor cursor = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).datasource.getCursor(false);
    int length = cursor.getCount();
    Number[] seriesWeights = new Number[length];
    String[] LABELS = new String[length];

    int i = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        seriesWeights[i] = cursor.getFloat(2);
        LABELS[i] = cursor.getString(1);
        i++;
    }

    //------ neues array mit interpolierten werten bauen
    int interp = 7; // diesen wert anpassen zum interpolieren

    int addNewDateIndex = (int) (interp / 2f);
    int newLength = (int)length / interp;
    Number[] seriesWeightsInterp = new Number[newLength];
    String[] labelsInterp = new String[newLength];
    float addiert, mw;
    int newIndex = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j + interp < length; j = j + interp) {
        addiert = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < interp; z++) addiert = addiert + (float)seriesWeights[j + z];
        mw = addiert / interp;
        seriesWeightsInterp[newIndex]   = (Number)mw;
        labelsInterp[newIndex]          = LABELS[j + addNewDateIndex];
        newIndex++;
    }
```

this array interpolates the values without respecting distances between dates.
what i want is to reduce the amount of data by interpolating them in "constant" timeframes, like months or 14-days....
so the algorithm has to check if the dates ares within the constant period and calculate the interpolation only for the values within the constant timeframes....

is this understandable?

bye
phil